# React Formik TypeError: this.props.formik.registerField is not a function

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, formik

I'm trying to implement a Form in my Gatsby application and I keep getting the below error

> TypeError: this.props.formik.registerField is not a function

I even [tried](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1368) downgrading Formik version but that did not work.

I'm currently using Gatsby version `2.13.3`, React version `16.8.6` and Formik version is `1.5.7`

**FormComponent.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from "formik"

const formComponent = ({ values, errors }) => {
  withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues() {
      return {
        hashtag: "",
      }
    },
    handleSubmit(values) {
      console.log(values)
    },
  })
  return (
    <Form>
      <Field type="text" name="hashtag" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default formComponent
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import FormComponent from "../components/FormComponent"
import "../styles/layout.scss"

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <FormComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage looks wrong, `withFormik` returns a function so you gotta pass your JSX/component into that, e.g. `withFormik({...})(MyComponent)`. Try something like this:

```
const formComponent = ({ values, errors }) => (
  withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues() {
      return {
        hashtag: "",
      }
    },
    handleSubmit(values) {
      console.log(values)
    },
  })(
    <Form>
      <Field type="text" name="hashtag" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </Form>
  )
)
```